# Remove objects from an array using underscore js or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I want to remove an object contains 'twitter' from the 'contents' array using underscore js.

```
contents = 
[
  {
     "facebook": "test",
     "preview_image_url": "url",
     "preview_title": "title",
     "preview_description": "description"
  },
  {
     "twitter": "test",
     "preview_image_url": ""
  }
]
```

Expecting result array as follows

```
contents = 
[
  {
     "facebook": "test",
     "preview_image_url": "url",
     "preview_title": "title",
     "preview_description": "description"
  }
]
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. Post your attempt to do your task above. The Underscore/Lodash documentation is pretty clear about how you can modify arrays with it.

Comment: Separately, you haven't said how you decided to remove the second entry but not the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you ever want a vanilla JS version:

```
var filtered = contents.filter(function (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).indexOf('twitter') === -1;
});
```

Or, taking on T.J's comment:

```
var filtered = contents.filter(function (obj) {
  return !obj.hasOwnProperty('twitter');
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, because the question says "I want to remove an object contains 'twitter'", and in the example there is only one instance of twitter and it's a key. But good point about `Object.keys` tho.

Answer (score 2):

Using [remove()](https://lodash.com/docs#remove):

```
_.remove(contents, _.ary(_.partialRight(_.has, 'twitter'), 1));
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer for its utterly arcane and obscure nature.